# How to create cloudwatch event using cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using cloudwatch scheduled event to trigger my lambda function after specific time interval. I would like to use cloud-formation template to add this rule in cloudwatch. I have gone through cloudformation templates documentation but I am not able to find out way to configure events using cloud formation template. Can anyone please suggest how to implement it using cloud formation template.

I am using below template.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Provision environment specific",
  "Resources": {
    "lambdaScheduler": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Event",
      "Properties": {
        "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
        "source": "aws.events",
        "name": "TEST_EVENT_10_MINS_RULE",
        "schedule-expression": "rate(5 minutes)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting `A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Unrecognized resource type: AWS::CloudWatch::Event` error message when I validate it using aws cli.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding CloudWatch event rules and schedules in now available, see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/04/amazon-cloudwatch-events-now-supported-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure the CloudWatch Event is yet to be exposed via the CloudFormation API. There is normally some lag between new features in AWS and them being implemented/exposed by the CloudFormation team.

Here is the list of resources currently available via CloudFormation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html

As one can see there is only one resource in the Cloudwatch namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried laying out your design in the CloudFormation designer? It only creates stub code for each element, but it validates the overall design. You then have to transfer the outline code to an editor to do the real work, but it should avoid the error you quoted.